# beamer's tableofcontents links to the wrong slide

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents

I compiled the following code 3 times to get the table of contents. The problem is that section names links to wrong slides. A links to B1 and B links to B2. So, it's wrong by one slide.
How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{A}
\frame{A}

\section{B}
\frame{B1}
\frame{B2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 'Works for me' with the current `beamer` release. I think `\lisitfiles` output would help here.

Comment: I got this
'beamer.cls    2011/09/12 development version 3.12 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)'
what version do u have?

Comment: I have 3.19 [I'm one of the `beamer` maintainers :-)]

Comment: ok thx:) i will update it to 3.19

Comment: Same problem here, I guess I will have to wait for MacTex2012.

Comment: @futureneo: Did updating solve your problem?

Comment: I confirm the same problem. I'm using the latest beamer package (2011.09).

Comment: This is not an answer but may help identify the problem. I use Windows XP, MikTeX 2.9 beamer 3.23 and this is a problem for Sumatra 2.1.1 pdf viewer but not for Adobe 9. I have read elsewhere that it is a problem for evince 3.4. So perhaps this is a problem with your reader.

Comment: @futureneo: Did you solve the problem, and in that case, how did you solve it?

Comment: @JosephWright: After adding `\listfiles` to the preamble, my log file tells me that I'm using `beamer.cls    2013/04/04 3.27 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision dca7db0ccda1)`. I still have the problem futureneo has, though. I use MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever There is an open bug for `beamer` about this: it only shows up with some viewers, although it may be to do with something in `beamer` and how stuff is added to the PDF.

Comment: @Joseph: The problem exists in the build-in viewer in TeXstudio, which I normally use. In Adobe Reader on the other hand, it works fine, so it definitely seems to be viewer dependent.

Comment: If your problem is the same as mine, I may have found the solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130783/13780

Answer (score 2):

I tested your example with TeX Live 2012 and it works well.

I use the following version:

```
beamer.cls    2011/09/12 development version 3.20 A class for typesetting pre
sentations (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
```

Comment: MikTeX 2.9 with version `3.22 A` works without any problems.

Comment: I use `beamer.cls    2013/04/04 3.27 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision dca7db0ccda1)`, and I still have the problem described in this question. I use MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: The bug only seems to exist in some document viewers, like for example the built-in viewer in TeXstudio which I use. In Adobe Reader on the other hand, the problem does not show up.