# Why does Beamer's table of contents items link to the second slide in a section?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents, viewers

When I include a table of contents in a Beamer slide show, each section entry in the TOC ends up linking to the second slide in that section. I would have expected it to link to the first slide. What am I doing wrong?:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test TOC}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Just to clarify: when I click *Section 1* in the TOC, it takes me to the slide *Test 2*.

UPDATE: I am actually not sure if it takes me to slide *Test 2*. When I click the link, the viewer (Evince and Okular) displays most of *Test 2*, but with a tiny strip of the slide *Test 1* visible at the top of the window. I suspect that the viewer may treat the link as pointing to the very bottom of slide *Test 1* and then aligns that with the top of the window. Could this be the explanation?

Comment: A problem with your packages; outdated, perhaps? In my system (TeX Live2013) everything works OK with your MWE.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am using TexLive 2013 too. I need to check my local texmf tree...

Comment: @JosephWright Indeed! I just checked and the problem appears using Evince! Have you (Thomas Arildsen) tried using another viewer?

Comment: I am using Evince too.

Comment: It happens in Okular as well.

Comment: And in Sumatra as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution, or maybe a workaround? The described problem appeared when viewing slides in "continuous" mode. If I disable this so that the viewer jumps from slide to slide instead of scrolling across them, clicking links **does** take me to the right slide. This goes for both Evince and Okular.

Answer (score 11):

This was due to a [bug in `beamer`](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/238), which only shows up with some viewers. The problem comes down to where the target is located for page links. The behaviour was to place this in a footer, which is not really correct. The code has now been updated to place the link in the 'correct' place during shipout, and this fix will appear in the upcoming v3.28 update to CTAN.

Answer (score 5):

As you already explained there is a workaround, until the beamer package is updated with the bug fix Joseph Wright mentions. By putting your PDF viewer in Single Page mode you are able to correct this behavior, which was also present in Adobe Acrobat 11 (and probably <11 as well). The simplest way, that doesn't require the viewer to select this view mode manually, is to add the `pdfpagelayout` option to your `hyperref` options, like so:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelayout=SinglePage}]{beamer}
```

Note that the `hyperref` options must be in curly brackets and supplied to the `hyperref` option of the `beamer` class. This is due to `beamer`'s dependency on the `hyperref` package, which it loads for you automatically.