# Beamer goes to next slide instead of the target slide

Tags: beamer

I am a new user of Beamer presentation template and noticed that when I click on an entry from the ToC it goes to the next slide instead of the target one. However, when I open the pdf file in a pdf viewer such as Foxit and click on the bookmark it goes to the right slide. Why is this discrepeancy cause and is there a solution for it?

Comment: Please post a Minimum Working Example demonstrating the problem. It is impossible to guess what might be wrong without seeing your code. There is no such discrepancy here.

Comment: This sounds like the bug in beamer which has been discussed here several times. According to [this answer by Joseph Wright](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136157/3954) the bug should be fixed in recent beamer versions.

Comment: As the other comments say, this sounds like a dupe: what `beamer` version do you have?